# What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name programmers.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

One of the big 7 questions.

- One answer per answer please
- Only .com domain names please
- Only untaken domain names please (use whois)

Please use **lowercase characters only** in domain name!
DomainName.com is more readable, but we have to register domainname.com!

Comment: Someone may go grab all posted domain names to be evil! Mwuhahaha!

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62734/renaming-the-not-programming-related-proposal/62849#62849

Comment: Went through all positive suggestions to improve their formatting so it lists the domains in the same size and the availability (did a whois check to confirm each too) right under it, the reason is listed last.

Comment: @TomWij why did you camelCase the names though?

Comment: @Noctrine: Also for formatting reasons, all SE sites have this behavior in their names and it makes the proposals stand out... If people dislike the case formatting I will revert it.

Comment: @TomWij: **lowercase only** please! While camel case is much more readable, we all know that DNS is lowercase only. So we have to take in account readability in lowercase only.

Comment: @TomWij: no problem, I understand your enthusiasm in making the names more readable!

Comment: @Lorenzo: My excuses, that's a good idea! (Typo:) I have only read the bullet points... :-(

Answer (score 31):

## outofscope.com

Taken / Available for purchase

[GoodEnough](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/220/goodenough) is the owner and willing to sell.

Comment: I'm a fan of that name.

Comment: I like it, it both defines the purpose of the site and the context.

Comment: This just topped offtopic for me, I think this is going to be the winner...

Comment: Made a logo proposal based on this one, check: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/274#274

Comment: This sounds about right. Catchy name as well

Comment: I dunno. I'd prefer something that isn't an anti-SO identifier, unless that's a clear goal for everyone else.

Comment: I like that it's not as much of a direct SO reference. I think it would be good for this site to be seen as a standalone relation rather than a subservient upstart...

Answer (score 19):

## offtopic.stackoverflow.com

Available.

Comment: I actually kinda like this one

Comment: I think this is my favourite so far.

Comment: Is this even a valid option? I do like it.

Comment: Do we really want to just be a subsidiary of SO, rather than our own site?

Comment: @Fisctoaster I don't know, Programmers is where most of the off topic SO questions go. If we do get out of public beta alive, there would be so many questions moved between here and SO that we would almost be a subsidiary of SO. I'm just worried about the stupidly long url to get to chat: `chat.meta.offtopic.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: The chat url would be chat.offtopic.stackoverflow.com but it would indeed still be long, the subdomain itself is also a bit long.

Comment: Consider [this SO blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) on why we might want our own identity.

Comment: @TheLQ such a long URL should be no problem for programmers :p

Comment: @TheLQ: Being a subsidiary of SO ain't that bad. And the name "programmers.stackoverflow.com" in itself is already causing confusing on SO itself. People are commenting on very much directly programming related questions that they are more suited to programmers.SO... They obviously haven't read the faq that PSO is intended for questions **indirectly** related to programming. So I would suggest to steer well clear of all names that imply programmers or programming in their name. Unless the offtopic part is also part of that name...

Comment: At first, this was my favorite suggestion: short and to the point. However, the more I think about it, the more I think it's the wrong choice. Using the domain *offtopic.stackoverflow.com* indicates that *all* off-topic Stack Overflow questions are okay here. But this site isn't the home of *all* off-topic questions: for example, "Is Justin Bieber dreamy?" and "Why doesn't my dog like me?" are just as off-topic here as they are on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Lorenzo personally, I don't necessarily believe "we have to definitely be a subdomain of SO". I like the subdomain model, but I also agree with the points outlined in the link posted by @fishtoaster.

Comment: According to http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-can-we-avoid-programmers-se-from-becoming-the-se-black-sheep these domain proposal seem like a very bad idea, to prevent the issue mentioned in that question we should be as far apart as we can be from SO... If not this will lead in the described effect and confusion, if we go through with this proposal we could as well create an offtopic subdomain from every site. SU could use one too... ;-)

Comment: Besides that, not all off-topic questions of SO are allowed here...

Comment: -1 offtopic != not programming related

Comment: +1 I think that we should definitely be a subdomain of SO, but I'd prefer **programmers.stackoverflow.com** or **basement.stackoverflow.com** or **banned.stackoverflow.com**.

Comment: -1 We will draw the wrong users and site attribute by going for basement/banned/blacksheep.SO... As said before, I think this issue and having a subdomain is a bad idea! And programmers.SO will be too confusing, it does not give away the difference between both sites... I don't see any point in up-voting a proposal that doesn't work out (**we are not the off-topic part of SO, only a small slice of it**), if you want one of the sub-domains to push through you will have to create a new proposal as else the community can't point out which one they like.

Answer (score 17):

## slackoverflow.com

Taken / Available for purchase

I proposed this on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62734/renaming-the-not-programming-related-proposal/62849#62849) and Jeff suggested to add it here too.

Comment: I had to stare at that for a few seconds before I noticed the L

Comment: Taken, but possibly still available to be purchased.  It's just parked with ads at present.

Comment: It's a great joke, but not a good URL for the real site.

Comment: I'm the owner, I'm willing to sell for a fair price.

Comment: As LordTorgamus said, it's a good joke, but not that great as an actual url.  It's too easy to mistake (either verbally or in writing) with stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 12):

## idlecoder.com

Available.

Comment: This one would fit fine in the current set of SE sites.

Comment: As there is still the possibility for this domain (or others if a miracle happens) to be chosen... Does anyone have an idea for a logo? How could we express idle and coding in a logo?

Comment: @TomWij I really like this one, I've been trying but the best I can come up with is one of the little XKCD dudes with a cup of coffee :p

Comment: -1. I'd like the site to be about working as a programmer. Not about what I'm doing when not-working. :)

Answer (score 7):

### programmerslife.com

Answer (score 5):

## notcoderelated.com

Available.

I like this more than *NotProgrammingRelated.com* because it is a more accurate representation of the direction this community is heading. We **do** talk about programming here, so first and foremost this community is most definitely *programming related*. That being said, the discussions stay away from physical code for the most part, and thus I believe that *NotCodeRelated.com* still conveys allows the name to convey a programming mindset, but it excludes the focus of Stack Overflow.

Just my two cents.

Comment: This tells what we aren't, but shouldn't we have something that tells what we are?

Comment: @TomWij this is good a point.

Answer (score 4):

## heapunderflow.com

Available.

In the same vein as [this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-our-domain-name-be/34#34).

Answer (score 3):

## idleprogrammer.com

Available.

Answer (score 1):

## compilationphase.com

Available.

[image]

<sub>Sorry, couldn't resist...</sub>

Comment: I could also get behind "ImCompiling.com" :D

Comment: Yeah, feel free to post similar domains, eg. ItsCompiling.com. The reason behind this one is that during the compilation phase one has time to "slack off" to finally have a subjective talk about the programming (instead of an objective talk about the code).

Comment: Slack off- or in some cases, break out into inter-office sword battles.

Comment: or [holy-wars] where they smite code across the room in some magic way, not to forget [boat-programming] where they take their hardware and software aboard and go for a battle on the sea. :-)

Comment: +1, that was my desktop background at work for a while.

Comment: Okay, this just gave me the idea to download all XKCD comics and let my desktop cycle through them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## notprogrammingrelated.com

Taken.

Owned by someone hosting a StackExchange 1.0 site.

Comment: Except it's not owned by Stack Exchange. It looks like someone used it to host either an SE1.0 site or a site using one of the open-source SE alternatives. But they might be willing to hand the domain back to StackExchange at a reasonable price.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. Updating now.

Comment: Empty site, registered to someone in Geneva. I hope we can get that domain back

Comment: Forgot to mention: **"Record expires on 10-30-2010"**

Comment: I think this is almost contrary to the direction this community appears to be heading. Not Programming Related suggests a topic of anything having nothing to with programming, when in fact, at best, we're "Not Code Related". All of our questions are about programming or the day-to-day surrounding programming, just none of them are focused on physical code.

Comment: It's a bit long... And this site does actually does allow subjective programming questions.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62734/renaming-the-not-programming-related-proposal/62849#62849

Answer (score 0):

### basement.stackoverflow.com

Idea taken from: [Is the Software Engineering site proposal a duplicate of programmers.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/is-the-software-engineering-site-proposal-a-duplicate-of-programmers-se):

> You absolutely nailed my resentment of Programmers.SE; it was created as a tongue-in-cheek, NOT-Stack-Overflow site: **the stuff we keep in the basement** because it's not fit for keeping upstairs.

Comment: No. There are enough reasons listed in this question to not choose that to be a subdomain. Hey, look... We're from the basement, we're the black sheep. This is a bad idea! It was created like that but shouldn't be like that.

Comment: What about **blacksheep.stackoverflow.com**?

Answer (score -1):

## pointertotheheap.com

Available.

What you can't store on the stack, put on the heap.

Comment: Nice tag line..

Comment: This name feels too "complicated".

Comment: I love this one, it's geeky enough, a bit of a pun... +1

Answer (score -1):

### programmersexchange.com

*Please forgive me... I had no choice...*

Comment: "programmers" is obviously plural in the domain name ... Who would have a dirty mind ?

Comment: Obviously @holyvier. It's almost as cool as ExpertSexchange, I mean http://experts-exchange.com

Answer (score -1):

## tabsvsspaces.com

available

Answer (score -3):

### coderoverflow.com

available

Answer (score -3):

## heappointer.com

Available.

Maybe also **heapointer.com** or **heap-pointer.com**

We all know about stack pointers, but what about heap pointers?

Answer (score -3):

## stackoverflowed.com

Available.

Answer (score -4):

## stackoverflowoverflow.com

Taken.

It's parked...

A handful of you may remember [Stack Overflow Overflow](http://stackoverflowoverflow.stackexchange.com/).

Why aren't other people using CW? Am I missing something?

Comment: To long, to easily confused with SO, thus not tab-complete friendly.

Answer (score -4):

## programmers.stackoverflow.com

Available.

It makes sense to keep it tighten with StackOverflow.com

Comment: Nope, don't agree. While keeping it tight with SO is a good idea, the current beta name "programmers.stackoverflow.com" in itself is already causing confusing on SO itself. People are commenting on very much directly programming related questions that they are more suited to programmers.SO... They obviously haven't read the faq that PSO is intended for questions indirectly related to programming. So I would suggest to steer well clear of all names that imply programmers or programming in their name. Unless the offtopic part is also part of that name...

Comment: If *programmers* is a subdomain of SO, the distinction would be clear to anyone. It seems the most reasonable place to put this site (as it is its companion site), and we don't necessarily have to find a humorous or evocative domain name.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted, considering the course nothingtoinstall.com has taken.

Answer (score -4):

## subjectiveoverflow.com

Available.

Answer (score -4):

## codebabble.com

Available.

Comment: Why were these downvoted?

Answer (score -4):

## devbabble.com

Available.

Comment: Why were these downvoted?

Answer (score -4):

### stackbar.com

Available

Answer (score -5):

## progpub.com

Available.

Short version based on a suggestion in [Renaming the Not Programming Related Proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62734/renaming-the-not-programming-related-proposal/62849#62849)...

Answer (score -5):

### communitywikis.com

I know, I know, not all q's are community wiki's, but almost all are :)

Answer (score -6):

### aboutcode.com

Looks like the domain is taken, but for sale. Not sure what the logistics would be.

Comment: I would use this as a last resort, but it just doesn't seem creative enough

Comment: @TheLQ Yeah, I like my "NotCodeRelated.com" a little more- which is ironically contrary.

Answer (score -6):

Several possibilities along the same lines:

### stackoverspill.com

Stuff that doesn't fit on StackOverflow.

### stackoverdose.com

People who can't get enough of StackOverflow come here too.

### stackoverride.com

The normal rules of StackOverflow don't apply here.

Comment: please use one unique name per answer so that votes can be associated with specific domains.

Comment: +1 for StackOverride, it clearly shows that Stack Overflow's rules about subjective questions do not apply here. Of course, they both form the short acronym "SO", which could lead to confusion.

Answer (score -6):

## professionalhacker.com

I'd imagine you'd have to spend more than 8.99 to get the domain, but it's not being used. I don't think we should stress idea that lame questions should be asked here if we're not going to accept them.  We'd probably be much improved if there was more than just the SO crowd coming to this site anyway.

You might object to the term "hacker". I'd take hacker in the "Pirates of Silicon Valley" sense that it's what you should answer when Bill Gates asks you what you do for a living. It might be an objectionable name, I do like "out of scope" but I don't know how useful it would be in the long term to only feed off the scraps of SO - as that name implies.

Answer (score -7):

### chatoverjoe.com

Playoff of StackOverflow - like a conversation around the coffeepot.

Available.

Answer (score -7):

programmersbackyard.com or theprogrammersbackyard.com

both available.

Answer (score -8):

## codingoasis.com

Available.

Comment: Sounds like another name for SO

Answer (score -9):

### stronginthesource.com

available