# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, site-attributes, top-7

One of the big 7 questions.

- One suggestion per answer please

[Logo guidance, from Jin](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot) (resident UI designer for at least some of the Stack Exchange sites):

> Please note: I prefer gray-scaled logo submissions, that way we can judge the IDEA of the logo more objectively. We can always add colors to the logo later. Also, the logo itself(sans the site title text) should be able to fit in a square dimension nicely. This way we can use it for favicons, mobile touch icons etc.

Comment: Perhaps we should wait on this until we can [come up with a domain](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-our-domain-name-be).

Comment: Also- community wiki!

Comment: @Nathan - This came up on one of the other sites. While the name will have an influence on the logo, the design should be independent.

Comment: @Nathan It shouldn't, most people are going to be putting their time into it and should get credit

Comment: @TheLQ: credit is not an issue on Meta, as you don't get or lose rep. Also, Community Wiki is [not for preventing rep gains](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-should-our-faq-contain/131#131). Community wiki would be useful here as it would allow logos to be collaboratively iterated.

Comment: I think we should let Jin come up with a few sketches.

Answer (score 12):

Supposing the current [best suggested name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-our-domain-name-be/116#116) might have a good chance to become our domain:

[image]

And an example of a tiny version which still needs some improvement through some pixel pushing:

[image]

**About the colors:**

We need to find a color that has a good characteristic for our site, maybe one that expresses subjectivity...
I think we should change the color of Scope. We can also place a vertical line with the color in the tiny version which denotes the typing cursor, as if one is willing to type something between the brackets.

Comment: /* Maybe with comment markers instead of curly brackets */

Comment: I don't think that would work well with the scope concept, and it is a problem for smaller versions...

Comment: Not sure about the exact implementation, but I love the idea.  Just like SO's logo, it simply and succinctly illustrates the name.  :)

Comment: +1 But I would like to drop the second bracket and just have: **} Out of Scope**

Comment: No, although the Super User logo had an influence on this idea, I think it is best to stay away from that by having two brackets. A single bracket in a small/tiny version will look too much like Super User... This logo is trying to stay apart from the Super User version. The only thing you might still think about is that those brackets are two discussing programmers, but I think it's best not to add an eye or mouth to keep the brackets related to programming.

Comment: @TomW Let us continue that thought and say, let us not use brackets at all!

Answer (score 12):

Here's a quick logo concept:

[image: Think outside the brackets]

I can work on an improved version (trying different fonts, positioning, etc), and do variants with motto/etc if people like the idea.

Comment: I was trying to think if I could represent 'wisdom' ( [see comment by Kate](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/410#410) ), but without implying 'discussion' nor making things too busy - let me know if anyone has thoughts on that?

Comment: Oh, and this was inspired by the "think outside the brackets" [motto suggestion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline/457#457) - just noticed the similarity with TomWij's smaller version. Heh.

Comment: It's a very good start to me.

Comment: The semicolons make them look like faces. Cool

Comment: I know I'm in the extreme minority here, but { :( } ( :) )

Comment: +1 Now that *is* clever.

Comment: Don't like the faces, I'd go with just the braces, personally.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is a logo involving a cup of coffee and maybe some faded code in the background. Kind of like this, but less crappy:

[image]

I don't know, it is perhaps a little too reminiscent of the Java logo.

Comment: I like it! Perhaps get rid of the coffee cup though (because of the Java association), and have a programmer typing or something in its place?

Comment: @Chinmay The main reason for the coffee cup was to convey conversation- i.e. over a cup of coffee. If someone can think of a better alternative I'm all ears.

Comment: What about the wine image on http://www.cuisinecapers.com/wine-the-subjective-response/ or some drawing deduced from it? Or some kind of meeting picture that clearly shows that there are programmers involved? (A less wide version of http://sha3teely.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/08/meeting.jpg)

Comment: @Nathan: I understand that, but as you yourself said, it's a bit too much like the Java logo. I can't think of a better alternative right now, but I'll give it some thought...

Comment: I like the faded code, but Chinmay is right... the coffee cup will carry too much Java connotation.

Comment: @Jim Leonardo Yeah, I completely agree.

Comment: There are a few problems with this submission: 1) it's a [word mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordmark_(graphic_identity%29) that doesn't work as a square [icon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_icon), 2) it doesn't work as a two-color (i.e. black-and-white) logo, and 3) the source code behind the word mark indicates we deal with coding problems, when we don't. Note [Jin's guidance on logos](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshot) from Gaming.SE.

Comment: Hey, you stole the layout concept from http://www.ticalc.org/ ! :)

Answer (score 3):

As long as it's not a copy-write issue.

[image]

The Concept of the logo is a combination of the stackoverflow logo and the meta.stackoverflow logo, hense the grey and colored rainbow.

I feel that the programmers site is a kinda of joining between both old sites so they meet together.

This was the orignal image from a meta image competion a while back.

All the talk of rainbows are making the logo a bit silly.

[image]

Comment: I like this. I dare say we could even just keep the right (gray) half. It would "complete" the SO logo per-se, and even still communicate the off-topic nature of this site. Heart pendants. Hah

Comment: You should mark this answer as community wiki, by the way.

Comment: I thought if the question was community wiki so were the answers, apologies.

Comment: It would need some color, grey is boring. And I wonder if we should show the relation with SO.

Comment: @Gordon You're right, the answers are marked community wiki *if the question is*; unfortunately, the question isn't marked correctly.

Comment: how about a different color for every brick? Like a rainbow.

Comment: *What about a double rainbow?* But serious, I don't think rainbows fit our site. :-(

Comment: This could totally be our theme song http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MX0D4oZwCsA

Comment: I see this logo like a dumping SO on P.SE.

Comment: Could someone explain me that thing with rainbows and unicorns?

Comment: Looks like the evil child of SO & meta. Oh, wait...