# Why is it that Programmers are Not Out of Beta yet?

Tags: discussion

I thought programmers SE should be out of beta long time ago, how come it's still not yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are next in line.

Jin is working on the design, but has decided on to do a redesign based on the feedback from [the first & second attempts](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/design-ideas-for-programmers-site-closed). Once that's been agreed we'll probably go live.

There's also a question on Meta Stack Overflow about [identifying questions to migrate from SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate) that indicates the go live date is imminent.

> http://programmers.stackexchange.com is *probably* going live this week,

Comment: What will be the domain?

Comment: @Pierre - http://programmers.stackexchange.com. There's been no talk of a domain and apart from Ubuntu, Seasoned Advice (cooking) and Cross Validated (stats) non of the other sites have their own domain.

Comment: Though http://nothingtoinstall.com does point to Web Apps even though it's not used in the title.

Comment: Money has the same setup with [basicallymoney.com](http://basicallymoney.com).

Comment: @C. Ross - forgot about that one, though it is an SE 1.0 site that converted to SE 2.0. As in [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) now that you remind me.

Answer (score 3):

Programmers.SE has been in beta for [99 days](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related): all Stack Exchange sites, barring some exceptional circumstances like a business-development deal (e.g. [Ask Ubuntu](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/)), stay in beta for at least 90 days. Many sites stay in beta for [significantly longer than that](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress).

We're currently next or second in line to leave beta: right now, Jin is [working on the final design](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/design-ideas-for-programmers-site-closed). Once that's done, we'll leave beta shortly thereafter.