# 404/Error/Captcha Images

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

I have started the CSS conversion of the [new design](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2), since it's gotten a lot of positive feedback this time. I'm aiming to launch the site very soon!

Meanwhile, I need some ideas for the new site's 404/Captcha/Error page images. Examples from other SE sites:

Cooking site's 404:

[image]

Gaming site's CAPTCHA

[image]
(Normally for Captcha, we do a "robot" theme.)

Photography site's 404

[image]

The idea is to have these images somewhat light hearted, and reflect the theme of the site. 
For the new Programmers site, I will make the images hand-drawn marker style. I need your help with coming up with ideas. You can either describe a concept, or link to an existing image that has the concept you have in mind. I'll recreate it hand drawn style.

Comment: I said before - go with the Lego recreations every time!

Comment: Isn't the Lego one Web Apps 404 page?

Comment: @ChrisF it is. Sometimes I use the same ones where I see fit.

Comment: How do we check the 500 error pages? ;)

Answer (score 23):

Maybe a coffee cup tumbled. Maybe over a keyboard.

Maybe a flow chart what the user should do to get an actual page.

Maybe both!

Comment: +1, I like the flow chart idea.

Comment: I like the flow chart. Perhaps a ridiculously complex or logically impossible one.

Comment: A spilled cup of coffee on a keyboard with 404 sketched out on the desk.

Comment: both are good ideas

Answer (score 11):

[image]

This one should be a fairly obvious Office Space reference

[image]

Somewhat related to Office Space (i.e. the printer) but the 00 error could be expanded for a 404 perhaps?

Comment: PC LOAD LETTER nails it!

Comment: -1 for me, I think Office Space is very US/Western World-centric, be good to have something a little more universal.

Comment: +1 from me. to cancel out your -1. which is very western-phobic

Answer (score 6):

A picture of a programmer sitting at their desk, typing away blithely, not realizing a cat unplugged the computer and the monitor is blank.

Answer (score 3):

An empty box of waffles might be a cool 404, but I don't know if everyone would get it.

Additionally, I think [most gems here](http://www.redditmirror.cc/cache/websites/www.rgbpicture.com_b3z9v/www.rgbpicture.com/wtf-photos-from-the-past.html) should be well out of copyright.

Comment: Could you let me in on it?

Comment: [I'm currently using waffles for my 404 page](http://joshuakehn.com/blog/view/12131).

Comment: +1 I skipped breakfast and now I hate you :)

Answer (score 3):

How about a silver bullet?  (Something that might be sought here and not found.)

Answer (score 3):

How about showing a computer in an office cubicle with the wording "there is no programmer" or "waiting for programmer to come back [from coffee session etc.]..." on the screen?

The computer/monitor can be an old school bulky one.

Comment: additional idea: "404 - Programmer not found."

Answer (score 2):

How about something resembling Stack Overflow's Search Results page when nothing's been found:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=somethingnotfound

(assuming no one's posted a question with that word in it).

Replace "somethingnotfound" with a phrase suitable for a Programmer's search.

Answer (score 2):

how about a screen showing cryptic compiler error output (e.g. error #404 designated resource identifier not found in web cache), with a motion-blurred hammer descending upon it?

Answer (score 2):

404: An empty coffee pot. Example found on Google Images:

[image: the horror!] ([source](http://www.underconsideration.com/wordit/archives/empty/))

Answer (score 2):

The current dog picture seems good.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like the flow chart idea in another answer.

Since a whiteboard fits pretty well with the idea that "something used to be here, but isn't anymore", you could go with the flow chart drawn on top of something half-erased - some sample code or bullet point list or maybe even multiple layers, like you see on most whiteboards around the office.