# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

The [new design](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2) has been deployed just now and I want to congratulate you guys for the official launch!

A few tweaks on the final design from the mockup I posted:

- I decided not to use the Yanone font since it is a bit narrow for question titles, especially on the homepage where the titles are repeated. I'm using Tahoma instead, same as the Beta theme.
- I used /* */ for the logo since a lot of people liked it. But I did leave a faint cameo for  } { as well. If the community feels strongly about using } { maybe the mods can open up a poll.
- CSS3. The final implementation uses some CSS3 elements, such as the button treatment, new user greeting box(same tips box on Ask/Edit pages), multiple background for the body doodles. Our web stats show close to 90% of users use CSS3 capable browsers, so I felt it was OK to do so. IE and older browsers should degrade gracefully.
- The right side doodle didn't make it in, because it'd clash with the content at lower res. However, I may work it in later, using media query.
- Error/404/Captcha images. For now I put in some place holders. Feel free to provide more feedback on the [official suggestion thread](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/404-error-captcha-images). Or, if you like what I put in, I can leave them.

  The new favicons are up, but the old ones may be cached by your browsers. You can always load the following URLs and hard refresh.

  http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/favicon.ico

  http://sstatic.net/programmersmeta/img/favicon.ico

If you see any CSS/Styling issues, please start a new question for the bug report, and tag it with "Design" and "Bug." It will be a lot easier for me to track new questions than reading the comments replied to this thread.

I typically fix CSS/usability issues asap. As for more subjective styling requests, I tend to let the new design simmer a bit. After having used the Beta Sketchy theme for a few months, it will take a bit of time to get used to the new design.

Thanks, and congrats again!

Comment: Just noticed... Looks great!

Comment: Thanks, Jin!  It's looking good.

Comment: I quite like the captcha and 404 images. Haven't been able to trigger an error though ;)

Comment: Came as a lovely surprise on my Android phone. Worked fine and looks great.

Comment: @ChrisF you can go there manually: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/error

Comment: @Jin - another thing I didn't know. Thanks. The image is good too - evoking SO's error page.

Comment: **Hooray!** ` `  ` `

Answer (score 5):

I really like the semi-erased white board background

Comment: Should be pink-tinged for added realism

Answer (score 3):

I was only vaguely aware a site appearance redesign was in the offing, and so when I clicked on a question I had displaying to see if anyone had added anything, suddenly everything changed! I was like "Whoa!" After a moment it all came clear, and I was ENLIGHTENED!

NICE! MUCH BETTER!

I didn't have a problem with the old design appearance, but this is a huge improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### It's quite harder to read,

at least for me.

Comment: What parts do you find harder to read? I like the new font in most places, but I found the main page's titles were harder to read for me too.

Comment: @Rachel - pretty much everything is harder to read. Just somehow does not feel right (for me).

Comment: ditto.. I'm not a frequent user anymore because it's difficult to read...

Answer (score 2):

## Love it!

Except the logo. In my opinion the logo [should be what was voted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like) rather then a few comments.

Also when loading a new page there is a *very* noticeable lag when swapping the fonts out. The nav bar overflows and then re-corrects when the new font drops in. Can this be fixed? (FF 4.b7)

Comment: The highest-voted logo `}Out Of Scope{` really only makes sense with the "Out of Scope" name.  `}Programmers{` would just make anyone who hadn't seen that thread wonder why the heck our braces were reversed.

Comment: @Tim: Why don't we keep `} Out Of Scope {`?

Comment: That logo discussion is out of date. "Out of Scope" was from the domain discussion which was closed when the domain-name idea was [put on hold](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-our-domain-name-be/).  Since **Out of Scope** is (at least currently) not the name, the brackets don't make much sense, as Tim says.

Answer (score 1):

Blood cell badges?  I liked the little "sunken" versions in the mockup

[image]

Comment: T, i decided to keep the badge style from the top bar and the in-page ones consistent. I liked the sunken style too, but it doesn't work on the sticky note background for the badges in side of the page. I just didn't want to use 2 different styling for the badges.

Comment: The sunken look at the top reads "disabled" to me.  Otherwise, I really like the new design.

Comment: It seems as though the badges changed...they are now erythrocytes that have not yet undergone anucleation `:D`