# Is there any significance ot the cat(?) in the 404 image?

Tags: support, design

[The 404 page of this site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/404) has an image of what looks like a cat:
[image: 404 cat]

Is there anything special about this cat? What does a cat have to do with software engineering?

Is it a historical inside-joke? Does it have a name? It looks very (mischeviously) happy. What is it so happy about?

I don't see this cat in [the post from 2010 soliciting 404 image ideas](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/668/414749). The closest thing I can find is [this suggestion](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/679/414749):

> A picture of a programmer sitting at their desk, typing away blithely, not realizing a cat unplugged the computer and the monitor is blank.

Is that it?

Comment: I think the main issue with this question is to find the right audience. Maybe someone from the staff can answer this, or [Jin](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1685/jin), who started the old post from 2010. But Jin seems not to be very active any more, maybe it is possible to contact him by Twitter?