# What's this cohhunity bulletin?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

I thought it was some sort of joke I'd missed out on because I'd pursuing glory in other SE's, but no... It's just community bulletin... So, is anyone going to do anything about the fact that the font is almost illegible?

As a programmer, I hate calling this a bug, but seriously Programmers Cohhunity you need to do something about this:

[image]

Perhaps someone has asked a Sihilar question?

**EDIT:** It's been over two months. Could somebody please choose a legible font?

Comment: I suggest an official rename of the bulletin to coHHunity. But then, your request will still remain valid - simply because we'd need font change to differentiate it from boring coMMunity. Oh and I see we are prograHHers not prograMMers

Comment: Programmers.SE mods can't do much about it. Only developers can. Best post this on Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: @Jae - nope. This is the right place. Tagged with [meta-tag:design] should ensure that Jin sees it

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks! Good to know!

Comment: ...so why haven't you complained that the site is called "PROGRAHHERS"?

Comment: @BenBrocka Prograhhers? I thought this site was called Droqrahhers! Now all the requests to change the name make sense!

Comment: Had never noticed, and never bugged me. Now I'm more confused about the change of direction in each letter, but I guess if that's just Laurie's hand-writing, I'll live with it.

Comment: I've always read this as "COHHUNKY BULLETIN".  It's a bad font.

Comment: "Illegible" is illegible for me.

Comment: Just because you programmers can't read your own handwriting...

Comment: Yup @ChrisF this heta is definitely the right place for this suggestion. *8')

Answer (score 13):

Blame it on [the font used for titles](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/site-design-round-2):

> The handwritten font in the title, top nav and section header is House Whiteboard. Yes, it is actually Hugh Laurie's handwriting. ("It's Not Lupus!")

Oh. Well then, blame it on Hugh Laurie. The limey bastard!

Comment: Very well, blame assigned.  I also blame him for none of the major browsers supporting the font-stretch css3 style which would have probably fixed it.

Comment: @PeterTurner I blame America's bad taste, if you waited for House M.D. to discover Hugh Laurie, you deserve his crappy handwriting ;P