# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, top-7

*We closed the [domain naming thread (click for details)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-should-our-domain-name-be).*

Instead, **let's start with a killer "elevator pitch!"** Joel will be blogging about the elevator pitch approach to naming, but to get you started:

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: Robert: I've already made [a similar question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-is-our-site-and-community-about) as a reaction on your blog posts. As part of your question is duplicate you might want to migrate and link from one question to the other...

Comment: Now that the domains question has been closed, what will we do with the [logos](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like)? Use Programmers as the logo text? Use no text at all? ...?

Comment: **Moderators** Feel free to merge and amend the resulting question with information from the other. Sorry about the duplicate. No need to have two threads.

Comment: Please see [@TomWij's question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/403/what-is-our-site-and-community-about) for more insight, but we only wanted one place for the answers.

Answer (score 28):

*(I like different parts from different responses, so I'm submitting this combined version.)*

Elevator Pitch: **A place for programmers to discuss problems that require wisdom, not clever code.**
OR
**Programmers is a site to share wisdom about the programming profession and subculture**
OR
[third option] *(see comments)*

Tagline: ***"Advice for programmers, by programmers"***

Motto: **Think outside the brackets.**

Logo Idea: ([see this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/473#473))
[image: Think outside the brackets]

*(I haven't included the Short Description because I think the existing FAQ description is mostly ok - personally I'd drop the "subjective" in the first line, and not mention code golf - but otherwise don't think it needs replacing.)*

Comment: I like the combination. I think this is exactly how I want the combination to be as well. +1

Comment: I like 'think outside the brackets'.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the "not clever code" part. Aside from the fact that we never actually want code to be clever, it feels like it's trying to be clever rather than informative. We want to *describe* what's on topic here, not define it via something symbolic. Also, "problems that require wisdom" sounds like it limits the scope to problems that are purely "wisdomous". I like the wording "share wisdom" better. You can share wisdom on problems that are of technical nature too, including that off-topic clever code.

Comment: I really like the motto and logo; I still prefer @EpsilonVector's elevator pitch (and I like your shared tagline). If you had @EpsilonVector's elevator pitch and tagline and your motto and logo, I think that would be the strongest suggestion yet...

Comment: Heh, whether code should be clever or not is perhaps a question for the site. :)

The point of that part is to differentiate it from the code-oriented problem solving nature of SO, but coming back to it now I agree that it's not quite right and the pitch should be more descriptive.

Comment: However, I'm still not convinced on the ending of EpsilonVector's pitch - what I'll do for now is put them both in this answer, but also have a think and see if I can come up with a better third option.

Comment: I think we going to have a winner here. Something between this answer and original @EpsilonVector. We need to decide in about 3 weeks. I invite for more opinions here.

Comment: I like the elevator pitch generally, but "programming" should be changed to "software development" - look at the list of things on-topic and you'll see they are so far beyond programming. The tagline should also reflect this.

Comment: "Think outside the namespace" might have worked, too.

Answer (score 16):

### Elevator Pitch:

"Programmers is a site to share wisdom about the programming profession and subculture".

### Tag line:

"Advice for programmers, by programmers".

### Motto:

I really don't think we need a marketing motto. It sounds more commercial than informative.

### Short description (for the FAQ):

It's a site for advice for programmers, by programmers, about the problems that arise from being a programmer. For the most part this would mean questions about the practice (coding standards, business of software, which library to use, workplace issues and setup, etc.), but sometimes, being the special breed that they are, programmers also come across life problems that are unique to them, like constantly being asked to fix people's computers, or the difficulty of explaining to people what you do, or how to write a CV (within the context of the industry), and is going to grad school worth it (again, within the context of the industry)... and these are OK too.

If you identify a question as something that is not Stack Overflow material, but you definitely need a programmer in order to get an answer, then it belongs to Programmers.

Comment: "Advice for programmers, by programmers" sounds like the perfect tagline for P.SE. The tagline seems to complement Paddyslacker's elevator pitch. Your elevator pitch is good too, though. +1

Comment: @Terence Huh... I didn't even realize how catchy it was until you pointed it out. *edit*...

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hmmm... On the one hand, I love everything about these. They embrace - nay, they *embody* the essence of both the site and the proposal that it grew out of. OTOH, these seem to encourage the sorts of "watercooler" conversations that are now frowned upon, and I fear would create confusion for new users. No matter; if P.SE is going to be *anything*, it should be this.

Comment: It's all about the watercooler!

Comment: I especially like the word "wisdom" - I think it's key to differentiating from SO. Knowing the C++ standard isn't about wisdom, but knowing how to talk to customers or bosses sure is.

Comment: I would prefter **Developers** in front of **Programmers** in the name to target a broader audience.

Comment: @Kate Thanks. Basically I was thinking about the difference between wisdom and knowledge when I wrote this. SO is about the knowledge, we're about the wisdom.

Answer (score 7):

Not very original, but I think that fits the site's *leit motiv*.

**Tagline**
Because programming is not just coding.

Comment: "programming != coding" ?

Comment: I think this one's the best. Not cliché.

Answer (score 5):

### Elevator Pitch

Where programmers discuss career management, industry trends, good ideas, bad ideas, co-workers, and other problems they can't solve with clever code.

### Tagline

Wisdom from fellow code monkeys who've Been There.

### Blurb

Code is the easy part.

Comment: I really like "problems we can't solve with code".

Answer (score 4):

### Elevator Pitch

*A site for programming professionals to ask and answer questions about non-coding problems.*

### Tagline

*Where programmers go when they need answers to non-coding problems.*

### Logo Blurb

*It's not about the code.*

Comment: I'd put it this way: *You've mastered coding.  Now discuss the rest with programming professionals*

Comment: @pavel That's nice, do you mind if I replace my tagline with your suggestion?

Comment: @paddy, of course I don't mind.  But I must warn you that I'm not a native speaker, and may have used not the accurate words.

Comment: Elevator Pitch is great. I can't think of any other way to describe P.SE. The Tagline, however, seems a bit off, IMO. I just can't point my finger to it. I'll get back to you when I figure it out.

Comment: @Terence i agree about the tagline. Pavel's tagline is an improvement on mine, but I think we could improve on "the rest". I'd love to hear what you come up with.

Comment: I've said similar before and I say it again, let's not be elitist. "You've mastered coding.." implies we do not welcome newbies.

Comment: @fearoffours - fair point, but what would you replace it with?

Comment: EpsilonVector's answer makes a pretty good tagline. Also, I kind of agree with fearoffours's view about being too elitist. I'd remove professionals from "programming professionals" in your elevator pitch. I mean, I'm still a student, I'm not a professional yet but I frequent this site.

Comment: Yup, I just upvoted @EpsilonVector's suggestions. I still like my motto, though!

Comment: Ummm...well, actually, it **is** about the code...maybe not **all** about the code, but...

Answer (score 4):

**Elevator Pitch**

A site exploring the big picture of programming and the practicalities of professional software development.

**Tagline**

Professional programming principles and practice.

**Logo Blurb**

Think outside the brackets

Comment: "Crack it without a bracket!" -- something  like this also comes to mind...

Comment: "Transcend Parenthesis" :)

Comment: "Think the brackets outside" (like a mental shift or smth) :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Tagline

Programmers: About.  By.  For.

Answer (score -1):

This site is about "being a programmer". So how about "To-1-Or-0-A-Programmer" or "ToBe or not(ToBe) a programmer"?

I like the first option better, also 1 OR 0 is 1 and that is the only option once you are one. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Quoting an old joke from memory (can't find the source)...

If a debugger is something used to find and remove bugs, then what do you call the ones that write the bugs?

Hence, in the spirt of site names such as StackOverflow and ServerFault, I suggest:

"If a debugger is something used to find and remove bugs, then what do you call the ones that write the bugs? Buggers - The ones behind the bugs."

Answer (score -3):

**Pitch**
Yeah, you can code, but what about the rest? Welcome to your new home.

**Tagline**
Living outside of scope.

**Motto**
/dev/discussion

Answer (score -3):

Elevator Pitch: Google.  For everything else there's Programmers@stackexchange.com.

Tagline:  Programmers@stackexchange.com - Where programmers give their 10 cents.

Motto:  Where people know what 0xCAFEBABE is.
[image]

Answer (score -4):

**Pitch**

Programmers on Programming. The collective wisdom and best practices of the software development community.  *The* place to go for answers on the art of programming.   100% code free.

**Tagline**

The Art of Programming.

**Motto**

No {} allowed

Comment: [Not anymore](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38/where-do-code-golf-code-challenge-questions-belong/446#446).

Answer (score -6):

#### Elevator Pitch *and* Tagline

*Experiences and advice from programming professionals*

The target subject matter for this site *still* seems rather... unclear. But this seems like a good fit. Where SO is targeted at pulling in technical answers from wherever, P.SE seems to value the voice of experience (or a reasonable imitation...)

#### Logo blurb

*Programmer-related*

I think it was Joel Coehoorn who coined this, originally to describe questions that *seemed* like they would belong on SO but didn't. Pithy...