# Can we change the name of the site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming the site to match it's FAQ or changing the FAQ to match the site name?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/renaming-the-site-to-match-its-faq-or-changing-the-faq-to-match-the-site-name)

Right now, it's "Programmers", which was a good name at the beginning. However, the FAQ contains so much more now (and I love the new topics for discussion here, except for code golf): software engineering, testing, tools/techniques, algorithms and data structures, design patterns, architecture, methodologies, QA, law, business concerns.

Although many people who are interested in these are programmers, I think a name that invokes engineering, craftsmanship, or development would be better. Lots of people interested in these topics are or were programmers, but these topics go far beyond programming and include people who aren't programmers (architects typically aren't programmers, but were at one time, as an example).

Comment: Right on. I think the name is confusing and puts off some great people - such as folks still holding out for the "software engineering" proposal, which as best as I can tell, the original proposal for that site is now included in the FAQ here...

Comment: I think we should use the term **Developers** instead of **Programmers** to target a broader audience.

Comment: @Jonas Developers is better than Programmers, but I'm not entirely sure it captures architects, law, and business. Perhaps, though.

Comment: Bad bad bad name. Check this out: 
http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/469/why-high-number-of-closed-questions-extremely-annoying

Comment: "Developers" can mean plenty of other things depending on what industry you're in, e.g. real estate developers.  Unless we are assuming that everyone who finds the site will be in software / IT, I think that's a confusing name.  "Software Developers" might be better ... although I also think it would be nice if the name conveyed that the site is for non-coding questions.

Comment: The name is too confusing - if it is a site for programmers to Q&A, then it is StackOverflow. This site is about "being a programmer". So how about "To-1-Or-0-A-Programmer" or "ToBe or not(ToBe) a programmer"?

Comment: code authors would be better

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the site goes live **and** gets "Server Fault levels of traffic" (source to follow) then we'll get a "proper" domain.

If we've chosen a good tagline, see [Write an Elevator Pitch/Tagline](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline) then the name should come.

**UPDATE**

Things have changed since I wrote this answer. The site has gone live, but the criteria for getting a top level domain have changed. As well as getting Server Fault levels of traffic (which we are probably approaching) we still need to have a good name, and except in rare circumstances sites don't get their own name any more.

Comment: @Tshepang - yes, but things have changed since I wrote this answer. Except in rare circumstances sites don't get their own top level domain any more.

Comment: @Tshepang - indeed. It's early in the morning for me, so I'm not fully awake yet.

Comment: I would be even more glad if you mentioned specifically that the site went live already. Either that, or delete `Assuming the site goes live` statement.

Comment: UI.stackexchange.com changed to UX.stackexchange.com, which IS much more suitable (even though it is only a letter away).