# Are questions about programmer relations and programmer development on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Born from the earlier question [Inclusion to the question topics section of the faq](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/inclusion-to-the-question-topics-section-of-the-faq) which asked whether 'programming psychology and philosophy' be added to the list of topics for questions in the FAQ, should we add *programmer relations* and *programmer development* to the FAQ instead?

*(Quoted from [an earlier revision](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/c8bb7de9-1814-423a-86bd-798f09913817/view-source) of the previous question:)*

> Questions that fall under 'Programmer relations' are those that concern teamwork, programmer to manager to stakeholder (or anyone in the development process?) etc...
>   Some examples from today are:
>
> [How can I get programmers to stop writing code vulnerable to SQL injection?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/68258/19799)
>
> [What is the best advice to give someone in this industry who resists change?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69111/19799)
>
> Questions that fall under 'Programmer development' are those that concern self improvement as a programmer, such as:
>
> [“The pragmatic Programmer” or “Clean Code”. which one would you get, and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69059/19799)
>
> [Suggestions to set goals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69176/19799)

Comment: -1: Consider carefully. Then kindly delete this question.

Comment: @Jim G - Why should this question be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topics of programmer interactions and professional development are generally on topic, but that doesn't mean that every question in those categories will remain open.

The topic is only a part of what contributes to the question staying open or closed. Some will be open because they are asked in a [constructive way](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and apply to a general internet audience. Some will be closed because they are too broad to be definitively answered or too localized to the asker. Some will be closed because they're not programmer-specific (i.e. questions about general coworker issues that are not limited to software development).

There is nothing in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) right now that prohibits these kinds of questions. So long as they fall within the guidelines described in the "What questions can I ask here?" sections and avoid the pitfalls of the "What questions should I not ask here?" sections, they should be fine.