# Can we put a tagline under our logo?

Tags: feature-request, design

Someone new to our site, or perhaps Stack Exchange might get the idea that our site is for any kind of programming related question.

Since migration with Stack Overflow is not bi-directional, I suggest that we decide on [an elevator pitch or tagline](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline) that lets people know that questions about the programming *industry* are welcome here.

Comment: It's better to post this request at MSO.

Comment: Did you raise this on MSO, or is this now dead?

Comment: @ChrisF It's a dead issue, I believe this was prior to the design being launched.